# Body:hover и z-index двух блоков?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, frontend

```
<body class="body">
<div class="banner_holder">
<div class="blc1"></div>
<div class="blc2"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

blc1=z-index: 2;
blc2=z-index: 1;

Как при наведении курсора на body сменить z-index?
blc1=z-index: 1;
blc2=z-index: 2;

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, немного подробнее. blc1 и blc2 должны меняться местами?

Answer (score 1):

```
body:hover .blc1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
body:hover .blc2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```